# Separate string that contains "_"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have the following

```
ex <- tribble(
  ~type,
  "a__0",
  "ab__10"
)

> ex
type
a__0
ab__10
```

I would like to separate by "_". The result would be

```
letter  extra
a       __0
ab      __10
```

*Note the double underscore*

but when I use the following

```
ex %>% separate(type,into=c("letter","extra"),sep = "_")
```

I get

```
letter  extra
a       
ab
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert a comma before the first underscore and then separate by comma:

```
ex %>% 
   mutate(type = sub("_", ",_", type)) %>% 
   separate(type, into = c("letter", "extra"), sep = ",")
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  letter extra
* <chr>  <chr>
1 a      __0  
2 ab     __10
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another idea. Separate the column and then add `__` back.

```
library(tidyverse)

ex %>% 
  separate(type, into = c("letter", "extra")) %>%
  mutate(extra = paste0("__", extra))
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   letter extra
#   <chr>  <chr>
# 1 a      __0  
# 2 ab     __10
```

Or use `extract` with capture groups.

```
ex %>%
  extract(type, into = c("letter", "extra"), regex = "([A-Za-z]+)(\\__[0-9]+)")
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   letter extra
#   <chr>  <chr>
# 1 a      __0  
# 2 ab     __10
```

Comment: regex =  "(.+)(__.+)"

Comment: @Nettle Thanks for your suggestion. Nice one.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a positive lookahead:

```
ex %>% separate(type,sep = "(?=_)", into = c("letter", "extra"), extra = "merge")
```

Answer (score 1):

str_split works here

```
a <- do.call(rbind , strsplit( c("a__0","ab__10"), "__") )
a[ , 2 ] <- paste0( "__", a[ , 2 ] )
```

If you don't want the "__" than don't run the second line